# jquery dialog: drag dialog at any point

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable

Is there a trick to make a jquery dialog be draggable at any point? (i mean not only in the title bar)

Comment: Good question, although I like the fact that it works like other windows, draggable by the title bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As opposed to a sortable item, dialog items doesn't have that functionality (I'm not sure why). If needed, you might be able to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var
        // Create dialog
        dialog = $('div')
            .dialog({ title: "I'm a dialog" })
            .css({cursor: 'move'}),

        // Get the options manually
        options = dialog
            .data("dialog")
                .uiDialog
                .data('draggable')
                    .options;

    // Finally, extend the draggable modal box's
    // options and remove any restrictions
    $.extend(options, {cancel: '', handle: ''});
});
```

​

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gMP2d/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#div_id")
    .dialog({
        position: [3,442],
        width: 300,
        height: 90
    })
    .css({cursor: 'move'})
    .parent()
    .draggable({cancel:'',handle:''});
```

Comment: Why are you taking the parent container of the $('#div_id') and not just making the $('#div_id') draggable?